# How to clear memory consumed by surface?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I am creating a surface and then sending it to the lower layers.
Something like this.

```
try{
Surface surface = StartCamera(surface, CameraId);
   }
 catch(Exception ex){
  }
```

Do I explicitly need to `surface = null;`?? 
I am getting exception as release not being called for surface.java.
Please let me know what is the correct procedure to clear up the memory so as not to get the exception?

Comment: Like the error says, call `release()` on it.

Comment: Call release() on what??
Since it is declared as a local variable shouldnt it be freed on its own ??

Comment: Most likely [Surface.release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#release()), but you'll want to use [Camera.release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release()) at some point, too.

Comment: u mean to say, in the finally block i should call surface.release()?
We have a seperate API for StopCamera. So I think that Camera.release is not required.

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue. You haven't given enough relevant code, nor a specific logcat error. However, if you get an error saying "release not called", then you need to call release somewhere. Have you read through any tutorials for using `Surface`?

Comment: I understand that. Yes I will try the release API and see if it works. I will try to post the specific error if it still persists. Thanks.